# Replace one field of CSV file based on entries in a second CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to merge 2 files together using `awk`. I want to print fields 1,2 from file1 as they are and replace field 3 according to a mapping stored in file 2.

**File1:**

```
1,top,yel
2,dress,bl
3,jeans,bl
```

**File2:**

```
bl,blue
yel,yellow
```

**Desired output:**

```
1,top,yellow
2,dress,blue
3,jeans,blue
```

**What I tried so far**

Here's the `awk` command I tried so far:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {seen[$3]=$1 "," $2;next} ($1) in seen {print seen[$1],$2}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

However when "bl" appears twice in file 1, the output only includes one of the occurences. In the above example it's missing line "2" from file1.

```
3,jeans,blue
1,top,yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your desired output, it sounds like what you actually want to do is read `file2.csv` first, creating a mapping between the fields, and then apply that to `file1.csv`

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} NR==FNR{clr[$1]=$2; next} {$3=clr[$3]; print}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Comment: thank you, can you explain what {$3=clr[$3] does?

Comment: @John it's a lookup, taking `$3` as the key and returning the corresponding value from the (arbitrarily named) array `clr`.

Comment: does the first $3 relate to the field number? Also could you kindly explain NR==FNR{clr[$1]=$2; next} - Thanks

Comment: @John it's the same syntax as your original `seen[$3]=$1 "," $2;next` except the index is the 1st column (instead of the 3rd) and the assigned value is the 2nd column (instead of a concatenation of the 1st and 2nd)

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question title and body to make the OP's intention more clear. If you want, you can remove the corresponding remark in your answer.